# How to solve Segmentation fault(core dumped) error in C using Code::Blocks in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I was running a linked queue data structure in C using Code::Blocks IDE.
Below is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedQueue
{
    int data;
    struct LinkedQueue *next;
}Q;
Q *front , *rear;

int QEmpty( Q * );
void QInsert();
Q *QDelete();
void QDisplay( Q* );


int main()
{
    int ans, choice;
    front = NULL;
    rear = NULL;
    do
    {
        printf("\n::Linked Queue Menu::");
        printf("\n  1. Insert ");
        printf("\n  2. Delete ");
        printf("\n  3. Display ");
        printf("\n  4. Exit ");
        printf("\n Enter your choice:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch( choice )
        {
            case 1: QInsert();
                    break;

            case 2: front = QDelete();
                    break;

            case 3: QDisplay(front);
                    break;

            case 4: exit(0);

        }
        printf("\nDo you want to go to main menu? (1/0) :");
        scanf("%d", &ans);
    }while ( ans == 1 );
    return 0;
}



void QInsert()
{
    Q *temp;
    temp = (Q*)malloc(sizeof(Q));
    temp->next = NULL;
    if( temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nMemory cannot be allocated");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nEnter the data:");
    scanf("%d", &temp->data);
    if( QEmpty( front ) )
    {
        front = temp;
        rear = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = temp;
        rear = rear->next;
    }
    printf("\nInsertion Successful");

}

int QEmpty( Q *front )
{
    if( front == NULL )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

Q *QDelete()
{
    Q *temp;
    temp = front;
    if( QEmpty( front ) )
    {
        printf("\nQueue Underflow!!");
        printf("\nReturning to main menu . . ");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe deleted element is %d.", temp->data);
        front = front->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
        free( temp );
    }
    return front;
}

void QDisplay( Q *front )
{
    if( QEmpty( front ) )
    {
        printf("\nThe Queue is empty");
    }
    printf("\nThe display of Queue is:\n");
    printf("!!!->");
    do
    {
        printf("%d", front->data);
        front = front->next;
    }while( front != rear );
}
```

When I ran this program, the insertion and deletion functions works fine. But when I called the display function, it resulted into a segmentation fault (core dumped).

Please help me how to solve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try stepping through the code, looking at the values using the debugger until they're not what they should be. Hint: what happens if a value is `NULL`?

Comment: wizzwizz4 gave very good advice: please familiarize yourself with the debugger, and get in the habit of using it: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks.  Please, too, be sure to "upvote" replies that were helpful, and "accept" the answer the resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input @paulsm ! I'm beginner in C. I'll refer that link for sure.

Comment: You should rewrite this to pass the pointers through parameters instead of using ugly global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from @evolvedmicrobe shows a bug in `QDisplay` in case your list is empty (i.e. when `front` is NULL).

This answer will focus on another bug in `QDisplay`.

Consider what will happen when **the list contains exactly 1 element**. In that case `front` and `rear` are identical. Further `front->next` is NULL.

So look at my comment in the order 1), 2), 3) and 4):

```
void QDisplay( Q *front )
{
    if( QEmpty( front ) )
    {
        printf("\nThe Queue is empty");
    }
    printf("\nThe display of Queue is:\n");
    printf("!!!->");
    do
    {
        printf("%d", front->data);  // 1) In first loop this will print the data from the first element (fine)
                                    // 4) In the second loop you deference front which is NULL => seg fault

        front = front->next;        // 2) Now front gets the value NULL

    }while( front != rear );        // 3) Front and rear differs so the loop continuees
}
```

(note: besides causing a bug when there is exactly 1 element, your approach is also bad for "more than 1 element" as you will never print the last element)

A better approach is:

```
void QDisplay( Q *front )
{
    if( QEmpty( front ) )
    {
        printf("\nThe Queue is empty");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nThe display of Queue is:\n");
    printf("!!!->");
    do
    {
        printf("%d", front->data);
        front = front->next;
    }while( front != NULL );   // or just } while(front);
}
```

Additional consideration:

Your code uses the global variable `front` and `rear`. In general I'll recommend that you **do not** use global variables. It's confusing and error prone. Instead you can define them in `main` and pass pointers to them to functions that need to change them. Or - perhaps better - place them in a struct so you can pass a pointer to a variable of that struct (define in `main`).

If you really, really, really think you need global variables, I'll strongly recommend that you **never** use the same name for local variables and function arguments. In other words: You `QDisplay` currently has an argument with the name `front` - just like the global variable `front`. That's kind of confusing... what will happen when you assign something to `front` inside `QDisplay`? Will the global `front` change? The answer is no but to avoid confusion it's better to use another name for the function argument. Like:

```
void QDisplay( Q *p )
{
    if( QEmpty( p ) )
    {
        printf("\nThe Queue is empty");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nThe display of Queue is:\n");
    printf("!!!->");
    do
    {
        printf("%d", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }while( p != NULL );   // or just } while(p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @4386427 ! It worked perfectly. I have some doubts.

Comment: 1) Since i used a do while construct to traverse the queue, it means i can still display 1 element ,right? like the condition while( front->next != NULL) occurs only after displaying first node?

Comment: 2) Since i used the front node to traverse, does this alter the position of the original front node? Is it better to assign front node to temp, (such as Q *temp; temp = front) and continue to traverse?

Comment: @AndrewJoel Regarding 2) No, it will **not** change the global `front` variable. You are confused about global versus local variables. Inside `QDisplay` it is a **local** variable because of you pass it into front. Try this to better understand: 1) use `void QDisplay( Q *tmp )` 2) change all `front` inside `QDisplay` to `tmp`. See the difference? That said - I'll recommend that you **do not** use global variables. And if you must use globals then avoid using the same name for local variables including function arguments.

Comment: your optional approach works just fine. So, you recommend me to use temp instead of global variable front?

Comment: @AndrewJoel yes.  if you must use globals then avoid using the same name for local variables including function arguments

Answer (score 2):

In your function `QDisplay`, you check if a pointer is null, but don't exit if that condition is true, but instead go on to dereference the pointer, which will cause a segfault.  You need to modify the method to return if queue is empty.  E.g.

```
void QDisplay( Q *front )
{
    if( QEmpty( front ) )
    {
        printf("\nThe Queue is empty");
        // Two lines below added by me
        printf("\nReturning to main menu . . ");
        return;
    }
 ...
```